# How to test Phoenix Channel that push result instead of reply?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I have a phoenix channel that does push result on a **handle_info** after a **handle_in** instead of replying right away (don't ask why please, I have a use-case). The example below would be similar to my case.

```
def handle_in("topic", %{"param" => param}, socket) do
    ... do something here ...
    send self(), %{:on_topic, result}
    {:noreply, socket}
end

def handle_info({:on_topic, result}, socket) do
    ... do something here ...
    push socket, "topic_resp", %{resp: result}
    {:noreply, socket}
end
```

So far I'm able to test the **handle_in** easily (since there is no reply), but how to wait and test the result of the socket push after **handle_info**?

Comment: [`Phoenix.ChannelTest.assert_push/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ChannelTest.html#assert_push/3)?

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert :)